# Jquery slideToggle show and hide, in one click

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following HTML :

> ```
> <tr>  
> <td></td>
>
> <td>9</td>
>
> <td>40.0</td>
> <td id="9" class="seecart">Voir</td></tr><tr><td colspan="4" id="detail_9" class="ADetailCart">
>
> qsdfqsdfqdf </td></tr>
> ```

WIth this JS :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.seecart').click(function(){
        $('#detail_'+$(this).attr('id')).fadeToggle();  
    });
});
```

When i click on my button the line is shown, and then hidden again. What is my problem? Before trying with toggle i tried to test if visible to slide and change a text but i had the same problem.

Comment: Ok, it is not a jquery problem, it is a rails problem, rails import twice the JS file

Comment: Hey! You changed totally your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got your code working here:

http://jsbin.com/ubameq

My guess is that your js is running twice.